# IConfiguration in .NET Core 7

Tags: configuration, jwt, get, token, microsoft.extensions.configuration

How I use

```
var _tokenOptions = Configuration.GetSection("TokenOptions").Get<TokenOptions>();
```

in .NET Core 7. I want my class named `TokenOptions` to be mapped by configuration. I can't use the get method. What can I use instead?

Please help me!

Comment: And ***WHY*** exactly can't you use the `.Get<TokenOptions>` method? Does it throw an error? If so: what error? Does it just not load any configuration settings - then most likely your section name is wrong or not present in the config file you're going against ....

Comment: No, I dont use. There was a get method in older versions. I could use it this way. How can I use it in the new version?